# Minimal example of fail-soft alpha-beta game tree including a fail-low

Tags: minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

While studying the fail-soft alpha-beta algorithm I'm struggling to come up with a minimal game tree which, when solved with fail-soft alpha-beta produces a fail-low which is different to the minimax value.

For example. Let the initial alpha and beta values be 2 and 4, respectively. Also let's say that the true minimax value of the root node is -2. Furthermore, let's suppose that the fail-soft alpha beta produces 0 for the root node.

Formally:

```
true_minimax(root_node) = -2
fail_soft(root_node, 2, 4) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
true_minimax(root) = 3
fail_soft(root, 6, 8) = 5
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqKPB.png)